# How to get what button was clicked on?

Tags: unity, c#, gui, interface

Other contexts in which this was done I'm sure have been answered for this kind of problem before. But this has thus far been a 2 week long impasse of wittling down all the other suggestions I've seen and not one has worked.

I've got a prefab GUI with a singleton instance based script, which automatically disables itself at the start (I've tried commenting that out to see if that was it). The gui has a title text, body text, and 8 buttons. The script is meant to allow other scripts for interactive objects to safely access it and "start a conversation", using a coroutine.

I created a script for the buttons that I attach to each, that when called should set a public bool to true, indicating it was clicked, this bool is polled among the buttons to see which button the user clicked. This is then return to the script which called the GUI, and the GUI closes or waits for the next piece of the conversation. I've set everything to be enabled, and removed anything that disabled the components. I've made sure that the buttons are higher in the hierarchy than everything else, to make sure nothing else was intercepting the clicks.

I'm unable to get OnClick, OnMouseOver, OnMouseDown to be called. Debug messages never show. I've tried setting OnClick as part of the GUI where you select a function from the list, and inside of the button's code by adding a listener manually to the button. I've tried IPointerExitHandler, IPointerDownHandler, etc, also never seen anything come back from the methods.

I've tried several other methods to date to get which button I clicked, such as ray casting when the mouse button is down and checking the name for the button's name, however it always passes through to the terrain. I've tried getting the button's rect and using Rect.contain with the mouse position to see if the mouse was over the button when clicked, but this never returns true.

I'm really interested in seeing a working example where something like this has been done, so that perhaps if that doesn't work, I could at least start hunting down what might be causing a functioning example to fail, as I've no idea what's wrong at this point. Not to vent but this is very frustrating, and I feel it could be made so much simpler.

Thank you all for any help you can give, you guys have been very wonderful with my short time here.

Comment: Sounds like you are having a hard time man.  You never mention the use of colliders.  You are using colliders right?

Comment: Yeah I made sure there were colliders. Still sorting it out. Thanks for commenting. Just gonna keep plugging at for a little more and then just try from scratch again to see.

Comment: Can you add some code and maybe a screenshot or two (of the inspector GUI, not the code)?